# Create web application to scan document

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-3.5

work on asp.net 08 C#.I would like to develop a web application that scan documents into the following format(pdf,tiff,jpg,gif.etc) .My scanned images/file will be at client computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using an 3rd party scanning control such as LeadTools? I have used those controls in the past and worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

Brining in a scanned document through the browser goes beyond the basic functionality of the browser.

If you must stick with ASP.NET, you might consider writing an ActiveX control (IE only, I think) that can handle the scanning and interact with your web page.

You might also consider Silverlight. Although I don't think it can handle the scanning directly, you should be able to interface with COM components installed on the system to handle scanned streams.

Comment: @incred Yes, my suggestions are indeed targeting MS solutions.  The question mentions ASP.NET and C#, which are MS-driven technologies. I would be very interested in hearing of non-MS solutions, though personally I'm not aware of those solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The wording is sort of ambiguous. Is the scanner on your side or the client's side? I understand that the result of the scan is saved on your client's side.

---

I assume that the scanner is on the client's side...

You can't access peripherals [ie: a scanner] via standard JavaScript...  You can take advantage of ActiveX for IE only.

Why not write a small winforms application in c# and let your client download that?

By the way, if the client has a scanner on his/her side, the scanner will likely have come with software to manipulate the scanner...

Comment: on my client side ,necessary software are already installer for scanner,now i need to scan ,client and scanner are in same network group .